# Using (R)Selenium to scrape the "experience" section from LinkedIn - webscraping the section: id="experience-section"

Tags: python, r, selenium, rselenium

This is a follow on post to my original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784161/scraping-data-from-linkedin-using-rselenium-and-rvest), however this is more specific to webscraping using R (however, I follow the `BeautifulSoup` and `selenium` Python libraries).

I have the following R code:

(What it does, is opens up an external Firebox browser, navigates to the LinkedIn login page, enters my own username and password and then clicks `enter`. So I am logged into LinkedIn, next it opens up Hadley Wickhams LinkedIn profile (through `remDr$navigate`) and then it downloads the page source of this page, finally it uses `rvest` web scraping, I keep an example of web scraping the profile name `profileName` to show a little how the code works, but I am trying to scrape the "Experience" section of the page).

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

userID = "myEmailAddress"
passID = "myPassword"

try(rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = 'firefox'))
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/login")    # go to login page

user <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"username")
user$sendKeysToElement(list(userID,key="tab"))

pass <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"password")
pass$sendKeysToElement(list(passID,key="enter"))    # logs in the user

Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load
remDr$navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/in/hadleywickham/")    # go to Hadley Wickhams profile page

Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]                             # downloads the page source code

signals <- read_html(html)

# Collect the profile header tag - name, location, etc.

profileHeaderTag <- signals %>% 
  html_nodes("div") %>% 
  html_nodes("[class='flex-1 mr5']")                      # locates the relevant tag for profile info


profileName <- profileHeaderTag %>% 
  html_nodes("ul") %>% 
  html_node("li") %>% 
  html_text() %>%                             # extract just the name of the profile person
  str_trim() %>%                              # removes unwanted white space (similar to .strip in Python)
  .[1]

profileName # which prints "Hadley Wickham"

######## Stuck here: ##############

signals %>% 
  html_nodes("ul")

# @ minute 22.06 of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVnBCtgS_-U
# The python code is:
# exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
# Where "soup" is the authors version of my "signals" R code.
# I want to find the 'experience-section' part but cannot get it working.

# When I click "inspect element" on the LinkedIn profile source code I find a section called:
#<section id="experience-section" class="pv-profile-section experience-section ember-view">
```

I would like to scrape the "Experience" section from a profile. I have seen how this is done in Python from the following [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVnBCtgS_-U) at minute 22.06 the Python code is `exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})`.

My problem arises trying to get this section in R, when I go to the LinkedIn profile and right click and press "Inspect Element" I can navigate to the source code which shows `<section id="experience-section" class="pv-profile-section experience-section ember-view">`. However, this part I cannot seem to process in my R session. (It seems to return an empty cell).

In Python I have followed the original Youtubes code and I still cannot get the "experience section" to print even in Python and it returns a "None" value.

Python code:

```
import requests, time, random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')     # need to download chromedriver and put it in the same directory
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')
userID = "myEmailAddress"
passID = "myPassword"

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(userID)

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(passID)

elementID.submit()

link = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/hadleywickham/'
browser.get(link)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

for i in range(3):
    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

src = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

name_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flex-1 mr5'})
name_div

name_loc = name_div.find_all('ul')
name = name_loc[0].find('li').get_text().strip()
name

exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
exp_section

print(exp_section) # which returns "None"
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this, or is LI blocking the scraping? I am facing the same issue in Python - identified the div classes for Experience section from "Inspect element" but unable to find the classes in the code (I'm also navigating to the page the same way as you are).